Question about the proper setup of exit alarms
Maybe you can help me with the following:
The problem is with the exit after TSL. On entry, I pass the initial value of the TSL (which is still an SL at the time) to the PineConnector. With the exit conditions, everything works to the extent that TradingView (TV) executes the exits in the chart exactly on the red line of the SL/TSL that I have created. I have now tried to include these conditions in the exit alerts by formulating and creating the test conditions. However, these exit alerts, as you can see them in the code, neither work in the triggering at TV, let alone are they transmitted to PC or utilized by MT4. After the MT4 has executed entries, the respective trade runs until the SL forwarded with the entry command has been reached again. As long as this is not the case, it logically holds the security position. (At the bottom left of the picture during the build-up of the impulse, you can see the entry point today at 0605. A sale should have taken place today at 0800 when the red line was reached. This did not happen for the reasons described above. The demo position currently stands at +€1116. Nice, you might think, but that's not the idea.
enter image description here
This is the relevant Part of my strategy including the code for the TSL and entries and exits
Many thanks
// © euler_daniel92

//@version=5
strategy("DCE Volume Swings MW", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500, max_boxes_count = 500, default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, process_orders_on_close=false, initial_capital= 45000)
var label last_debug_label = na


account_size = input.float(45000, title="Account Size (€)", minval=1)  // Kontogröße

risk_percent = input.float(1, title="Risk per Trade (%)", minval=0.1, maxval=100)  // Risiko pro Trade in Prozent

// ATR-Parameter und Multiplikatoren für SL und TP

atr_length = input.int(50, title="ATR Period", minval=1)  // Standardperiode für ATR

//atr_multiplier_sl = input.float(1.5, title="SL ATR Multiplier")  // SL-Multiplikator für ATR

//atr_multiplier_tp = input.float(2.0, title="TP ATR Multiplier")  // TP-Multiplikator für ATR

atr_value = ta.atr(atr_length)  // Berechnung des ATR-Werts

// Einstellung für die Glättungsmethode des ATR

atr_smoothing_type = input.string("SMA", title="ATR Smoothing Type", options=["ALMA", "HMA", "SMA", "SWMA", "VWMA", "WMA", "ZLEMA", "EMA"], tooltip="Choose the smoothing method for ATR")

 

//ATR Eingabe {

// Berechnung des ATR basierend auf der gewählten Glättungsmethode

if atr_smoothing_type == "ALMA"

    atr_value := ta.alma(ta.tr(true), atr_length, 1, 6)  // Hinzufügen von Standardwerten für offset und sigma

else if atr_smoothing_type == "HMA"

    atr_value := ta.hma(ta.tr(true), atr_length)

else if atr_smoothing_type == "SMA"

    atr_value := ta.sma(ta.tr(true), atr_length)

else if atr_smoothing_type == "SWMA"

    atr_value := ta.swma(ta.tr(true))

else if atr_smoothing_type == "VWMA"

    atr_value := ta.vwma(ta.tr(true), atr_length)

else if atr_smoothing_type == "WMA"

    atr_value := ta.wma(ta.tr(true), atr_length)

else if atr_smoothing_type == "ZLEMA"

    atr_value := ta.ema(ta.tr(true) + ta.tr(true) - ta.tr(true)[math.floor((atr_length - 1) / 2)], atr_length)

else

    atr_value := ta.ema(ta.tr(true), atr_length)  // Standard ist EMA, falls keine andere Auswahl zutrifft

//}

// ADX-Parameter und Schwellenwert
adx_length = input.int(14, title="ADX Length", minval=1)  // ADX Periode (Glättung)
di_length = input.int(14, title="DI Length", minval=1)    // DI Periode (Directional Indices)
adx_threshold = input.float(25, title="ADX Threshold", minval=1, maxval=100)  // Schwellenwert für ADX

// ADX-Berechnung des separaten Indikators mit neuer DI-Länge
dirmov(len) =>
    up = ta.change(high)
    down = -ta.change(low)
    plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0)
    minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0)
    truerange = ta.rma(ta.tr, len)
    plus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(plusDM, len) / truerange)
    minus = fixnan(100 * ta.rma(minusDM, len) / truerange)
    [plus, minus]

adx(dilen, adxlen) =>
    [plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen)  // Verwende `dilen` für die DI-Berechnung
    sum = plus + minus
    adx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen)
    adx  // Rückgabe des ADX-Werts

adx_value = adx(di_length, adx_length)  // `di_length` für DI, `adx_length` für ADX-Glättung



//use_tsl = input.bool(false, title="Use Trailing Stop-Loss (TSL)")

 

var string entry_direction = na

var float trigger_high = na

var float trigger_low = na

var int trigger_index = na

var float entry_price = na  // Variable zur Speicherung des tatsächlichen Einstiegspreises

var bool trade_executed = false  // Kontrollvariable für den Einstieg im Triggerfenster

 

calculate_position_size(entry_price, stop_loss_price) =>

    risk_amount = account_size * (risk_percent / 100)  // Risikobetrag pro Trade

    risk_per_unit = math.abs(entry_price - stop_loss_price)  // Abstand zwischen Einstiegspreis und Stop-Loss

    position_size = risk_per_unit > 0 ? risk_amount / risk_per_unit : na  // Verhindert Division durch Null

 

source = close

hilow = ((high - low)*100)

openclose = ((close - open)*100)

vol = (volume / hilow)

spreadvol = (openclose * vol)

VPT = spreadvol + ta.cum(spreadvol)

window_len = 28

v_len = 14

 

price_spread = ta.stdev(high-low, window_len)

v =  spreadvol + ta.cum(spreadvol)

smooth = ta.sma(v, v_len)

v_spread = ta.stdev(v - smooth, window_len)

shadow = (v - smooth) / v_spread * price_spread

out = shadow > 0 ? high + shadow : low + shadow

 

src = out

src1=open

src2=low

src3=high

 

tf =input.int(defval = 60, title = "TimeFrame", minval=1)

len = timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier >= 1 ?

   tf / timeframe.multiplier * 7 :

   timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier < 60 ?

   60 / timeframe.multiplier * 24 * 7 : 7

 

c = ta.ema(src, len)

plot(c,color=color.red)

 

o = ta.ema(src1,len)

plot(o,color=color.blue)

show_trend_lines = input.bool(false, title="Show Trend Lines (Red & Blue)")


plot(show_trend_lines ? c : na, color=color.red)  // Rote Linie nur anzeigen, wenn `show_trend_lines` aktiviert ist
plot(show_trend_lines ? o : na, color=color.blue)  // Blaue Linie nur anzeigen, wenn `show_trend_lines` aktiviert ist
 

// === Angepasster Code zur Füllungssteuerung ===

col = c > o ? color.lime : color.orange

 

// Schalter zur Steuerung der Füllung und der Linien

show_fill = input.bool(false, title="Linien und Füllung anzeigen")  // Checkbox im Einstellungsmenü

 

// Plot der Linien und Füllung nur anzeigen, wenn show_fill aktiviert ist

m1 = plot(show_fill ? c : na, color=col, linewidth=1, transp=60)

m2 = plot(show_fill ? o : na, color=col, linewidth=2, transp=80)

 

// Füllung nur anzeigen, wenn show_fill aktiviert ist

fill(m1, m2, color=col, transp=show_fill ? 70 : 100)

 

vpt=ta.ema(out,len)

 

// INPUTS //

st_mult   = input.float(1,   title = 'SuperTrend Multiplier', minval = 0, maxval = 100, step = 0.01)

st_period = input.int(21, title = 'SuperTrend Period',     minval = 1)

 

// CALCULATIONS //

up_lev = vpt - (st_mult * ta.atr(st_period))

dn_lev = vpt + (st_mult * ta.atr(st_period))

 

up_trend   = 0.0

up_trend   := close[1] > up_trend[1]   ? math.max(up_lev, up_trend[1])   : up_lev

 

down_trend = 0.0

down_trend := close[1] < down_trend[1] ? math.min(dn_lev, down_trend[1]) : dn_lev

 

// Calculate trend var

trend = 0

trend := close > down_trend[1] ? 1: close < up_trend[1] ? -1 : nz(trend[1], 1)

 

// Calculate SuperTrend Line

st_line = trend ==1 ? up_trend : down_trend

 

// Plotting

show_supertrend = input.bool(false, title="Show SuperTrend", group="Display Settings")

plot(st_line[1], color = trend == 1 ? color.green : color.red , style = plot.style_cross, linewidth = 2, title = "SuperTrend")

buy=ta.crossover( close, st_line) and close>o

sell=ta.crossunder(close, st_line) and close<o

//plotshape(crossover( close, st_line), location = location.belowbar, color = color.green,size=size.tiny)

 

 

plotshape(buy, title="buy", text="Buy", color=color.green, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)  //plot for buy icon

plotshape(sell, title="sell", text="Sell", color=color.red, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)  //plot for sell icon

 

multiplier = input.float(title="TP", defval=1.5, minval=1)

 

src5 = close

len5 = input.int(title="TP length", defval=150, minval=1)

 

offset = 0

 

 

 

calcSlope(src5, len5) =>

 

    sumX = 0.0

 

    sumY = 0.0

 

    sumXSqr = 0.0

 

    sumXY = 0.0

 

    for i = 1 to len5

 

        val = src5[len5-i]

 

        per = i + 1.0

 

        sumX := sumX + per

 

        sumY := sumY + val

 

        sumXSqr := sumXSqr + per * per

 

        sumXY := sumXY + val * per

 

 

 

 

 

    slope = (len5 * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (len5 * sumXSqr - sumX * sumX)

 

    average = sumY / len5

 

    intercept = average - slope * sumX / len5 + slope

 

    [slope, average, intercept]

 

 

 

var float tmp = na

 

[s, a, i] = calcSlope(src5, len5)

 

 

 

vwap1=(i + s * (len5 - offset))

 

sdev = ta.stdev(close, len5)

 

dev = multiplier * sdev

 

top=vwap1+dev

 

bott=vwap1-dev

 

 

 

//

 

z1 = vwap1 + dev

 

x1 = vwap1 - dev

 

 

 

low1 = ta.crossover(close, x1)  

 

high1 = ta.crossunder(close, z1)

 

 

 

plotshape(low1, title="low", text="TP", color=color.red, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)  //plot for buy icon

 

plotshape(high1, title="high", text="TP", color=color.green, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)  //plot for sell icon

 

 

 

// === Trend Indicator A ===

 

ma_type = input.string('WMA', 'MA Type', options=['ALMA','HMA','SMA','SWMA','VWMA','WMA','ZLEMA','EMA'], group="Indicators Setup")

 

ma_period = input.int(200, 'MA Period (Length)', minval=1, group="Indicators Setup")

 

alma_offset = input.float(1, 'ALMA Shift', 0, 1, 0.05, group="Indicators Setup")

 

alma_sigma = input.int(6, 'ALMA Deviation', minval=1, step=1, group="Indicators Setup")

 

 

 

show_line_1(x) => input.bool(false, 'Show Close line', group="Indicators Setup") ? x : na

 

show_line_2(x) => input.bool(false, 'Show High/Low lines', group="Indicators Setup") ? x : na

 

show_fill(x) => input.bool(false, 'Show fill', group="Indicators Setup") ? x : na

 

 

 

f(x) =>

 

    switch ma_type

 

        'ALMA' => ta.alma(x, ma_period, alma_offset, alma_sigma)

 

        'HMA' => ta.hma(x, ma_period)

 

        'SMA' => ta.sma(x, ma_period)

 

        'SWMA' => ta.swma(x)

 

        'VWMA' => ta.vwma(x, ma_period)

 

        'WMA' => ta.wma(x, ma_period)

 

        'ZLEMA' => ta.ema(x + x - x[math.floor((ma_period - 1) / 2)], ma_period)

 

        => ta.ema(x, ma_period)  // Standardfall, falls keine andere Auswahl zutrifft

 

ha_open = f(request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open))

 

ha_close = f(request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close))

 

ha_high = f(request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high))

 

ha_low = f(request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low))

 

ma_value = f(ha_close)

 

trend_line = ma_value

 

 

 

ha_trend = 100 * (ha_close - ha_open) / (ha_high - ha_low)

 

color_positive = input.color(color.new(#26A69A, 0), 'Positive color (Bullish)')

 

color_negative = input.color(color.new(#EF5350, 0), 'Negative color (Bearish)')

 

color_trend = ha_trend > 0 ? color_positive : color_negative

 

 

 

trend_color = color_trend  // Farbe der Linie aus color_trend bestimmt den Trend (grün = bullish, rot = bearish)

 

 

 

// Checkbox zur Steuerung der Anzeige der Heikin Ashi Linien

 


show_fill_between_trend = input.bool(false, title="Show Fill Between Trend Lines")  // Für Nummer 2
show_ha_lines = input.bool(false, title="Show Heikin Ashi Lines")  // Für Nummer 6
show_ha_fill = input.bool(false, title="Show Heikin Ashi Fill")  // Für Nummer 7
 

 

 

plot(ha_open, 'Open line', na, display=show_ha_lines ? display.all : display.none)

 

plot(ha_close, 'Close line', show_line_1(color_trend), 2, display=show_ha_lines ? display.all : display.none)

 

plot(ha_high, 'High line', show_line_2(color.gray), display=show_ha_lines ? display.all : display.none)

 

plot(ha_low, 'Low line', show_line_2(color.gray), display=show_ha_lines ? display.all : display.none)

 

 

 

 

 

fill(plot(ha_open), plot(ha_close), color.new(color_trend, 50), 'Open/Close Cloud')

 

fill(plot(ha_high), plot(math.max(ha_open, ha_close)), show_fill(color.new(color.gray, 87.5)), title="High Cloud")

 

fill(plot(math.min(ha_open, ha_close)), plot(ha_low), show_fill(color.new(color.gray, 87.5)), title="Low Cloud")

 

 

 

// === Impulse MACD ===

 

lengthMA = input(45, title="IMACD Length MA")

 

lengthSignal = input(21, title="IMACD Signal Length")

 

 

 

calc_smma(src, len) =>

 

    var float smma = na

 

    smma := na(smma[1]) ? ta.sma(src, len) : (smma[1] * (len - 1) + src) / len

 

    smma

 

 

 

calc_zlema(src, length) =>

 

    ema1 = ta.ema(src, length)

 

    ema2 = ta.ema(ema1, length)

 

    d = ema1 - ema2

 

    ema1 + d

 

 

 

src_IMACD = hlc3

 

hi = calc_smma(high, lengthMA)

 

lo = calc_smma(low, lengthMA)

 

mi = calc_zlema(src_IMACD, lengthMA)

 

 

 

md = (mi > hi) ? (mi - hi) : (mi < lo) ? (mi - lo) : 0

 

sb = ta.sma(md, lengthSignal)

 

sh = md - sb

 

 

 

mdc = src_IMACD > mi ? (src_IMACD > hi ? color.lime : color.green) : (src_IMACD < lo ? color.red : color.orange)

 

// Checkbox zur Steuerung der Anzeige der Plots

 

show_impulse_macd = input.bool(false, title="Show Impulse MACD Indicators", inline="ImpulseMACD")

 

 

 

plot(0, color=color.gray, linewidth=1, title="MidLine", display=show_impulse_macd ? display.all : display.none)

 

plot(md, color=mdc, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACD", style=plot.style_histogram, display=show_impulse_macd ? display.all : display.none)

 

plot(sh, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseHisto", style=plot.style_histogram, display=show_impulse_macd ? display.all : display.none)

 

plot(sb, color=color.maroon, linewidth=2, title="ImpulseMACDSignal", display=show_impulse_macd ? display.all : display.none)

 

 

 

// IMACD und Trend Indicator A Bedingungen

 

imacd_signal_long_condition = sb > 0.05

imacd_signal_short_condition = sb < -0.05

trend_long_condition = high > trend_line and low > trend_line and color_trend == color_positive

trend_short_condition = high < trend_line and low < trend_line and color_trend == color_negative

 

 

 

// SuperTrend V Indikator-Signale (Triggerkerze)

 

// SuperTrend V Indikator-Signale (Triggerkerze) mit zusätzlicher Bedingung für die Lage zur Trendlinie

 

buy_label = ta.crossover(close, st_line) and close > o and close > trend_line  // Kauf-Triggerkerze nur über der Trendlinie

sell_label = ta.crossunder(close, st_line) and close < o and close < trend_line  // Verkaufs-Triggerkerze nur unter der Trendlinie

 

if (buy_label and close > trend_line and imacd_signal_long_condition)

    trigger_high := high

    trigger_low := low

    trigger_index := bar_index

    entry_direction := "long"

 

if (sell_label and close < trend_line and imacd_signal_short_condition)

    trigger_high := high

    trigger_low := low

    trigger_index := bar_index

    entry_direction := "short"

 

if bar_index > trigger_index + 3

    trigger_high := na

    trigger_low := na

    trigger_index := na

    entry_direction := na

    entry_price := na  // Zurücksetzen des Einstiegspreises

    trade_executed := false  // Zurücksetzen der Kontrollvariable nach dem Triggerfenster

 

within_trigger_window = bar_index > trigger_index and bar_index <= trigger_index + 3

// Dynamische Positionsgröße und Entry Logik

position_size = (account_size * (risk_percent / 100)) / 100  

 //  Tailing Stop Realisierung   {

//MW Variable Declaration ATR Multiplier

float atr_multiplier_Long = input.float(1.5,"ATR Multiplier Long", minval = 0.1, step=0.1)

float atr_multiplier_Short = input.float(1.5,"ATR Multiplier Short", minval = 0.1, step = 0.1)

//MW calculate Stop Loss

var float TrailingStopLoss = na

float longStop = low - (atr_value * atr_multiplier_Long) //Berechnung der Distanz zum theoretischen Stoploss in Long Richtung

float shortStop = high + (atr_value * atr_multiplier_Short) //Berechnung der Distanz zum theoretischen Stoploss in Short Richtung

 

//Check if Trades and calculations are possible / ATR muss Werte enthalten - am Anfang der Kerzen ist kein Trade gültig

bool canTakeTrades = not na(atr_value)

bgcolor(canTakeTrades ? na : color.red)

//Nachziehenden  SL je nach Richtung berechnen

if (strategy.position_size > 0)

    if(na(TrailingStopLoss) or longStop > TrailingStopLoss)

        TrailingStopLoss := longStop

else if (strategy.position_size < 0)

    if(na(TrailingStopLoss) or shortStop < TrailingStopLoss)

        TrailingStopLoss := shortStop

else

    TrailingStopLoss := na  //wenn keine Trade vorhandne ist, wird die Variable auf NA gesetzt, damit kein Verlauf im Chart dargestellt wird

//Show the calculated long and short Stop

//plot(longStop, "Long Stop", color.yellow)

//plot(shortStop, "Short Stop", color.lime)

plot(TrailingStopLoss, "Stop Loss", color.red, 1, plot.style_linebr)

buy_condition = strategy.opentrades == 0 and within_trigger_window and entry_direction == "long" and high >= trigger_high and not trade_executed and canTakeTrades and adx_value > adx_threshold

sell_condition = strategy.opentrades == 0 and within_trigger_window and entry_direction == "short" and low <= trigger_low and not trade_executed and canTakeTrades and adx_value > adx_threshold  

//Long Position: Einsiteg
if buy_condition

    entry_price := close

    long_stop_loss = entry_price - (atr_value * atr_multiplier_Long)

    position_size = calculate_position_size(entry_price, long_stop_loss)

    long_message = '7782847873237,buy,' + syminfo.ticker + ',sl=' + str.tostring(long_stop_loss) + ',risk=1.8,lots=' + str.tostring(position_size)

    if not na(last_debug_label)
        label.delete(last_debug_label)
    last_debug_label := label.new(bar_index, low,
                                   text="Debug Entry: " + long_message,
                                   yloc=yloc.belowbar,
                                   color=color.green,
                                   textcolor=color.white,
                                   size=size.small)

    strategy.entry("Long Entry", strategy.long, qty=position_size, comment = "Long Entry: " + str.tostring(entry_price))

    // Alarm auslösen
    alert(long_message, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    
    //label.new(bar_index, high, text="Einstieg bei Long: " + str.tostring(entry_price, "#.#"), yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)

    trade_executed := true


/// Short-Position: Einstieg

if sell_condition

    entry_price := close

    short_stop_loss = entry_price + (atr_value * atr_multiplier_Short)

    position_size = calculate_position_size(entry_price, short_stop_loss)

    // JSON-Nachricht für den Alarm
    short_message = '7782847873237,sell,' + syminfo.ticker + ',sl=' + str.tostring(short_stop_loss) + ',risk=1.8,lots=' + str.tostring(position_size)

    if not na(last_debug_label)
        label.delete(last_debug_label)
    // Neues Label erstellen
    last_debug_label := label.new(bar_index, high,
                                   text="Debug Entry: " + short_message,
                                   yloc=yloc.abovebar,
                                   color=color.red,
                                   textcolor=color.white,
                                   size=size.small)

    strategy.entry("Short Entry", strategy.short, qty=position_size, comment = "Short Entry: " + str.tostring(entry_price))
    
    // Alarm auslösen
    alert(short_message, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

    //label.new(bar_index, high, text="Einstieg bei Short: " + str.tostring(entry_price, "#.#"), yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, size=size.small)
    trade_executed := true

// Alarm-Generierung für Long-Positionen
if (strategy.position_size > 0 and close <= TrailingStopLoss)
    exit_long_message = '7782847873237,closelong,' + syminfo.ticker
    alert(exit_long_message, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    // Debug-Label für Visualisierung
    label.new(bar_index, low, 
              text = "Alarm: Long Exit\n" + exit_long_message, 
              yloc = yloc.belowbar, 
              color = color.red, 
              textcolor = color.white, 
              size = size.small)

strategy.exit("Long Exit", "Long Entry", stop = TrailingStopLoss, comment_loss = "Long Exit mit Trailingstop \n" + str.tostring(TrailingStopLoss, "#.#"))

// Alarm-Generierung für Short-Positionen
if (strategy.position_size < 0 and close >= TrailingStopLoss)
    exit_short_message = '7782847873237,closeshort,' + syminfo.ticker

    alert(exit_short_message, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
    // Debug-Label für Visualisierung
    label.new(bar_index, high, 
              text = "Alarm: Short Exit\n" + exit_short_message, 
              yloc = yloc.abovebar, 
              color = color.green, 
              textcolor = color.white, 
              size = size.small)

strategy.exit("Short Exit", "Short Entry", stop = TrailingStopLoss, comment_loss = "Short Exit mit Trailingstop \n" + str.tostring(TrailingStopLoss, "#.#"))


//close bei der nächsten Kerze, wenn der StopLoss überschritten wird - Hosenträger zum Gürtel


This is the code of my strategy including the code for the TSL and entries and exits:
Strategy.exit (problem)
https://pastebin.com/SR4budVK
I hope you can open it

The description of your problem is confusing. Could you explain it in other words?

The posted image is blurry. I don't see a problem.

Your script looks fine https://www.tradingview.com/x/ny8L1mdi/
